# Calculating a limit always returns a zero in the denominator

Tags: limits

[image]

The problem is that $k$ is an element of the Natural numbers with zero and the $1/x^k$. Whatever I do, L'Hospital, Product rule of lim, ... , nothing seems to work and I always end up with a zero in my denominator.

Please, I have already worked 15 hours on this example. Any single help is highly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If I use J.W Tanner's answer, then I'm still stuck with infinite/infinite. Please help.

Comment: you could use L'Hopital's rule about $k$ times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Substitute $y=\dfrac1x$.  Then it's $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{e^y}.$

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. But why can we just substitute this and why does the limit change?

Comment: @smalllearner: the limit doesn't change.

Comment: @TonyK ok thanks, why can we just substitue?

Comment: @smalllearner We can just subsitute because it's the same limit, just with a different notation. You likely know the representation $f(x)=x^{-1}$. All that has been done here is we have said $f(x)=x^{-1}$, and now let's for simplicity write $f(x)$ as $y$. Absolutely nothing has changed because that $x^{-1}$ is encapsulated in the $y$, it is still in the equation it just looks different now. Notice though, the limit now goes to infinity as opposed to zero, because as $x\rightarrow 0$, $y\rightarrow \infty$: we have to ensure we are not changing the result.

Comment: @VividKraig Alright, thanks.a lot. But if I use J. W. Tanner's answer, I still get infinite / Infinite. Please help me

Comment: @smalllearner If you apply L'Hospital's rule the deniminator will never change. Continue to apply L'Hospital's rule until you are left with a constant in the numerator and $e^y$ in the denominator. What then is the limit?

Comment: @VividKraig Oh ok. Thank you so much for helping me! The limit should be 0 because constant divided by infinite is 0. Thank you so much!